# Basis for the null space of an identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is the set containing only the zero vector a basis for the null space of an identity matrix?

Comment: **Hint**: What is the null space of an identity matrix?

Comment: There are no parameters, so I end up with a vector containing 0's.

Comment: It cannot have any basis because a basis always contains linearly independent vectors whereas $0$ is not a linearly independent vector. So it is better to say that the null space of the identity matrix is the zero vector. Do not bring "basis" into this. Nullity is zero.

Comment: @ahorn Precisely. Only the zero vector is a null vector of an identity matrix. This, the dimension of the nullspace is...?

Comment: So the basis is $\{\emptyset\}$?

Comment: @ahorn No, the basis is $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any set of vectors containing the zero vector ${\bf 0}$ is linearly dependent; so no basis of any vector space contains ${\bf 0}$.

Since the identity matrix is invertible, its null space is the trivial vector space $\{ {\bf 0} \}$ (which contains only the zero vector). Now, any basis of a vector space $\Bbb V$ is a subset of $\Bbb V$, and so the only subset of $\Bbb V$ that doesn't contain ${\bf 0}$ is the empty set, $\emptyset$.

On the other hand, $\emptyset$ is a basis for $\{ {\bf 0} \}$ if we choose the convenient convention that an empty sum of vectors is the zero vector ${\bf 0}$.

Answer (score 0):

The null-space of an identity matrix is, indeed, a space containing only zero vector.

On the other hand, it has empty basis. The definition of basis - a family of linearly independent vectors that generates the whole space. Clearly, any family of vectors containing a zero vector is never linearly independent.

Comment: Agreed. And the zero vector cannot generate the span.

Comment: @ahorn not quite. Any vector can generate a vector space (its linear hull).

Comment: so, in this case, the span is **$0$**?

Comment: @ahorn yrs, the span of the zero vector is the zero vector space.